# Stacking canvases removes default transparency HTML

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas, css-position

I have this html:

```
<section id="contain">
  <canvas id="canvas-1" class="subcanvs"></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas-2" class="subcanvs"></canvas>
</section>
```

and this CSS:

```
#contain{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
.subcanvs{
  position:absolute; /*pay attention to this line*/
  width:100%;
}
```

When the two canvases are absolutely positioned and stacked,the container turns white.

When I remove absolute positioning, everything works out okay and it all goes the correct color with the background being red and the canvases being transparent, as they should be.

So how do I make two canvases stack AND make them both stay transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container is collapsing and taking your canvases with it!

Make sure you define at least width and usually height in container objects.

This code works in IE, Chrome and Mozilla:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#contain{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}
.subcanvs{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="contain">
      <canvas id="canvas-1" class="subcanvs"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvas-2" class="subcanvs"></canvas>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh so that's what's happening. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the very helpful answer by markE, I discovered what was going wrong with my design.

In light of this, I discovered another way to deal with it using CSS3.

```
#contain{
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}
.subcanvs:first-child{
  position:static;
}
.subcanvs{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

This will make all the canvases line up nicely on top of eachother if they are all the same size. I'm not sure of browser compatibility on this one.